# Resource not found when changing to landscape mode

Tags: android

When I change to landscape mode I want to save informations, I wrote this code, but when I start the program it shows *ResourceNotFoundException*, why?

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {
    int value = 0;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_b);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        //Toast.makeText(this," svd : "+savedInstanceState,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            value = savedInstanceState.getInt("count");
            text.setText("" + value); // here is the Error! why ?
        }
    }

    public void Incrementation(View view) {
        value++;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("count", value);
    }
}
```

**LOG**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.othma.udemy/com.example.othma.udemy.ActivityB}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x6*
```

Comment: Can you post detailed log information. Looks like the above code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to handle your logic in onCreate properly.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_b);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    //Toast.makeText(this," svd : "+savedInstanceState,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        value = savedInstanceState.getInt("count"); // here where we retrieve back the value
    } else {
       text.setText("" + value);  //first time init savedInstanceState will be null
    }
}
```

I think you need to reorder this also.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("count", value);  // used to store data before pausing the activity.
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Hope that helps!